# Don't understand this proof of the maximum principle.

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, quadratic-forms

In the proof of Lemma 1 in [this article](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eqze/notes/ELLIPTIC%20PDE/wmp.pdf), why does the equality
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{a_{ij}}\xi_i\xi_j = tr(\xi^T\tilde{A}\xi)$$ hold?  Is $j$ supposed to be held constant?

This looks like a quadratic form, but I don't understand why the equation holds.

Comment: you've typed an equality?

Comment: In any case, checking the link, it looks like a typo, i think it should be $$\sum_{i\color{red}{,j}=1}^n \tilde a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j=\operatorname{Tr}(\xi^T\tilde A\xi)$$